# Merge rows in specific number

Tags: r

I am currently working on drawing a volcano plot so that I need to calculate the fold-change and p-value. The data is extremely large so I first did some modification in R.

```
table <- read.csv("Sample_OTU_table.csv")
head(table)
table <- matrix(colMeans(table[,2:157]))
```

Now you can see a matrix which is 156X1

```
> head(table)
      [,1]
[1,] 0.3950838
[2,] 0.1429951
[3,] 0.1280243
[4,] 0.1098179
[5,] 0.1831748
[6,] 0.3418168
```

It is the means of each of 20000+ data in one column.

I am thinking of merge the rows, such as row1, row2, row3, calculate its mean (in this example, it is (0.39+0.14+0.12)/3), and leave the row4. Then merge row5, row6, row7 and leave row8. So that the matrix will be a 78X1 matrix. Then by using the code

```
newpairs <- as.matrix(pairs, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

We can split the matrix into two columns X 39 rows matrix, then using the package simpleaffy, the function

```
pc <- get.fold.change.and.t.test(eset.rma,"table",c(",1",",2"))
```

will give the fold-change and p-value of the pair variables. Then the volcano plots will be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowsum` for that: Example using mtcars data from R

```
mymat<-as.matrix(mtcars[1:7,1])
group<-c(rep(1,3),2,rep(3,3))
xsum <- rowsum(mymat, group)
> xsum
  [,1]
1 64.8
2 21.4
3 51.1
```

If you want to generalize: 
`mymat` is your matrix

```
set.seed(1)
mymat<-as.matrix(rnorm(156))

 head(mymat)
           [,1]
[1,] -0.6264538
[2,]  0.1836433
[3,] -0.8356286
[4,]  1.5952808
[5,]  0.3295078
[6,] -0.8204684
x<-rep(seq(1,nrow(mymat)/2,2),each=3)
y<-seq(2,nrow(mymat)/2,2)
z<-c(x,y)
group<-sort(z)
xsum <- rowsum(mymat, group)

head(xsum)
         [,1]
1 -1.27843910
2  1.59528080
3 -0.00353156
4  0.73832471
5  1.78217413
6  0.38984324


  dim(xsum)
[1] 78  1
```

Comment: @Metrics yeah that could work. But the problem is in this way, for my data, the script will be like group<-c(rep(1,3),2,rep(3,3),4,rep(5,3)...78) which is not very convenience.

Comment: You can use the "generalized code" in that case . See the updated answer.